# 3 way frequency table with percentages

Tags: r

I am trying to create a frequency table with 2 interacting x variables and 1 y variable. I want to display totals (both column and row) and percentages (ideally both column and row but column probably more important).

I have a dataset bgt, containing exam results split over 2 years (hence 'year'). These are then divided into question type (cat) and then have an outcome (google_cat). So I want to have a table with year in column 1, cat in column 2 (i.e., for one year type 1, type 2 then type 1 type 2 again for the second year and so on).

I have tried using

1. crosstable of the crosstable package

`crosstable(bgt, year, by=c(cat, google_cat), total="both", showNA="always",  percent_digits=0, percent_pattern="{n} ({p_row}, {p_col})") %>%  as_flextable()`

[image]

As you can see this puts the cat variable across the table but I want it down the left grouped with year. I tried doing that below but as you can see it just split the two x variables apart.

`crosstable(bgt, c(year, cat), by=google_cat, total="both", showNA="always",  percent_digits=0, percent_pattern="{n} ({p_row}, {p_col})") %>%  as_flextable()`

[image]

2. I also tried CrossTable from gmodels but this doesn't seem to support 3 variables. I tried ftable and xtabs

`three_way <- xtabs(~ year + cat + google_cat, data=bgt) ftable(three_way)`

but this just produced a very simplistic graph and other than applying prop.table to it I couldn't not work out to add in percentages.

Hope this makes sense - I have tried reading lots of different stackexchange fora and just can't find a solution to what I presume is a common problem with producing basic descriptive tables. Quite often I need to produce tables with mixed column and row percentages - sometimes with 2 interacting x variables and 2 interacting y variables. Sometimes even more than that - but I can't find a package in R that does this. And I don't want some fancy piece of base code creating functions - ideally a nice package that is easy to use and reproduce in different datasets.

Answer (score 0):

So, I hope you allow to recap the specific example described and change the variable names slightly.

- You have a number of observations for the variables `exam_qcat` (values: "cat_sba", "cat_vsa") and `exam_qtype` (values: "easy", "hard", "medium").
- You have this for multiple `exam_year`'s (2020, 2021).
- You want to create a cross table of the two categorical variables `exam_qcat` and `exam_qtype` for each `exam_year`.
- You wish to show percentages in the cross table.
- You want to stack the cross tables (*personal note: might be difficult to understand for some audience*).

Next, I give you one example how you could do this. The dplyr, gt and gtsummary packages will be used.

```
set.seed(123)

dat <- dplyr::tibble(
  id = 1:90,
  exam_year = c(rep(c("2020", "2021"), times = c(36, 54))),
  exam_qcat = c(rep(c("cat_sba", "cat_vsa"), times = 45)),
  exam_qtype = factor(
    sample(c("easy", "hard", "medium"), 90, replace = TRUE),
    levels = c("easy", "medium", "hard")
  )
)

## cross-table for year 2020
tbl_2020 <- dat |>
  dplyr::filter(exam_year == "2020") |>
  gtsummary::tbl_cross(
    row = exam_qcat,
    col = exam_qtype,
    percent = "cell"
    ) |>
  gtsummary::bold_labels()

## cross-table for year 2021
tbl_2021 <- dat |>
  dplyr::filter(exam_year == "2021") |>
  gtsummary::tbl_cross(
    row = exam_qcat,
    col = exam_qtype,
    percent = "cell"
  ) |>
  gtsummary::bold_labels() 

## stack the two cross-tables
gtsummary::tbl_stack(
  list(tbl_2020, tbl_2021),
  group_header = c("Year 2020", "Year 2021")
  ) |>
  gtsummary::as_gt() |>
  gt::tab_options(
    row_group.background.color = "grey70"
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `datasummary()` function of the `modelsummary` (disclaimer: I am the author). This page gives a detailed tutorial on the powerful formula interface, which allows you to create ultra-customized tables in virtually any structure you like: https://modelsummary.com/vignettes/datasummary.html#datasummary

We use the same data as @xx0020:

```r
dat <- data.frame(
  id = 1:90,
  exam_year = c(rep(c("2020", "2021"), times = c(36, 54))),
  exam_qcat = c(rep(c("cat_sba", "cat_vsa"), times = 45)),
  exam_qtype = factor(
    sample(c("easy", "hard", "medium"), 90, replace = TRUE),
    levels = c("easy", "medium", "hard")
  )
)
```

Then, load the `modelsummary` package and run the following code:

```r
library(modelsummary)

datasummary(
    exam_year * exam_qcat + 1~ exam_qtype * (N + Percent() * Format(digits = 1)) + 1 * Format(digits = 1),
    data = dat
)
```

[image]